# Allow tags on company pages to be clickable to see more jobs related to a tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On a specific company page it lists the tech stack via tags like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/quicken-loans

Look towards the center of the page.  If you hove over these tags you get the impression that they may be clickable as they change background styles.  To my surprise they aren't clickable.

Feature request, make these tags clickable and redirect to the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/NAMEOFTAG

Where name of tag is a technology stack, for instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/sql

Comment: How about a link to companies search filtered by that tag?

Comment: Dean that seems logical, certainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the report Jon!

I agree with @DeanWard on this one. This is fixed, clicking the tags listed under *Tech Stack* on company pages would now take you to companies search filtered by that particular tag.